# How to validate this deprecated function

Tags: functions

I want to validate this deprecated function:

```
add_filter('user_has_cap', array(&$this, 'filter_user_has_cap'), 10, 3);
```

It needs to use roles or capatibilies, so I guess 10 is the admin level, so I could use "edit_pages":

```
add_filter('user_has_cap', array(&$this, 'filter_user_has_cap'), 'edit_pages', 3);
```

But what is argument "3"?

Thank you
Oliver

Comment: Just FYI, the `10` is the *filter priority*, and is an argument to `add_filter()`, *not* to the *callback*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it's not the add_filter() call that you're supposed to be modifying, but the callback: 'filter_user_has_cap', i.e. go to where that method is defined and change the user level to 'edit_pages'.

Fixing deprecated notices is easier with the [Log Deprecated Notices](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/log-deprecated-notices/) plugin.